# how to define occurance indicator in xml schema (occur in all elements or does not occur at all)

Tags: xml, xslt, schema, xsd

I have the following xml schema.

I can restrict the maximum and minimum limits on occurrence but how can i define restriction that f1 should occur in all elements of field or should not occur at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<xs:element name="fields">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="field" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="f1" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="f2" type="xs:integer" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thinking I think I now understand what you mean. You don't want f1 to occur in all or none of the child elements of `<field>` like I thought but you want it one level higher: you want all `<field>` elements in one `<fields>` parent to either have an `<f1>` child, or none of them. That's still not possible in xml schema 1.0 and in xml schema 1.1 only with an xpath-assertion. It's also *not* a natural way of modelling with the concept of types used by the xml schema specification.

However it is easy to model *something like* what you want if you create different types of fields within the `<fields>` parent. Say you have one complex type assigned to an element '' which has a required '' child, and one other complex type assigned to an element `<field>` which cannot have such a child at all. You can then easily say using a `<xs:choice>` that all children of `<fields>` should be either `<f1field>` or `'.

**Schema**:

```
<xs:element name="fields">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="field" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="f2" type="xs:integer" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="f1field" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="f1" type="xs:integer" />
                        <xs:element name="f2" type="xs:integer" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**XML**:

```
<fields>
    <f1field>
        <name>x</name>
        <f1>3</f1>
        <f2>2</f2>
    </f1field>
    <f1field>
        <name>x</name>
        <f1>3</f1>
        <f2>2</f2>
    </f1field>
    <!-- Next field will be rejected by validator because there are 
         already f1field elements -->
    <field> 
        <name>df</name>
        <f2>5</f2>
    </field>
</fields>
```